# There is some kind of special character in someone's username

Tags: discussion, display-names, zalgo

I just viewed [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54196901/i-want-to-detect-place-order-button-click) where a user has some kind of special character in their username. I am sorry - I don't know what I should call this thing so that's why I am using the phrase "special character".

[image: Stack Overflow post with username circled]

You can see the profile of that user **[here](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8179151/m%CD%8C%CC%93%CD%AC%CD%AB%CC%A8%CC%B9%CC%96%CC%B1%CC%A0%CC%AD%CC%A0%CC%B1%CC%98a%CD%91%CD%AD%CD%9D%CC%A7%CD%94%CD%87%CC%97%CD%96%CD%96t%CC%86%CD%97%CC%8A%CD%ABt)**. Can someone kindly inform me if such kinds of things are allowed on Stack Overflow.

Comment: It’s [Zalgo text](https://meta.stackexchange.com/search?q=zalgo).

Comment: See also [How does Zalgo text work?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6579844/113848) for details.

Comment: I think Zalgo text isn't allowed (by policy) in usernames. Someone should flag that user for moderator attention.

Comment: MSE reference: [Why is a moderator on one SE site allowed to change my username across all communities?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/290993/why-is-a-moderator-on-one-se-site-allowed-to-change-my-username-across-all-commu).  Essentially, Zalgo text is not allowed in user names because of the side effects (another reference: [Zalgo in user names and effects on comments rendering](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/247022/zalgo-in-user-names-and-effects-on-comments-rendering)).  So mods will change the user name to remove this

Comment: good luck to ping this user :)

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre Thanks I am reading all the comments and answer

Answer (score 17, accepted):

As per [this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/290993/350567) and its answer on MSE, such username isn't allowed on Stack Ôverflow as it actively harms the functionality (readability and user experience) of SO. <s>In this case someone should flag one of their posts for moderator attention, explain that the username isn't suitable on SO.</s> I have already flagged one of their posts for mod's attention and explained that the username is disruptive.

**Update**: My flag was deemed helpful and their username has been changed to *matt* (no more Zalgo).

To be clear, a username like this is disallowed:

> oͦͦͦͦͦͦͦͦͦͦ

while a username like this is probably harmless (even if it looks ugly)

> L'ôšçáŗ ɖ'åmăñʈ

To be even clearer, the second one only makes itself ugly (and to some people, intrusive), while the first one damages the readability of text above it (the interfered text doesn't belong to the username).

Comment: I got confused when viewing your answer on a mobile browser because only the first o̊ in the "Username like this is disallowed" example without the other circles ascending, which would be allowed as the ring diacritic. But now that I've seen it from my laptop, I can see the full oͦͦͦͦͦͦͦͦͦͦ.

Comment: I find the bottom username is more disruptive than the top username you posted, the top one is just a snowman with a ball to the right for me

Comment: No offense, but, um, [are you really qualified to tell us not to use special characters in our usernames](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/350567/%C9%AAb%E1%B4%9C%C9%A2)?

Comment: @pizzastaticvoidmain It's not as simple (broad) as special characters. In fact, special characters *are* allowed, but extended Zalgo that disturbs other content are disallowed.